# Application single instance wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm trying to create an application that can have only one instance, and instead of don't opening a second instance I want to "raise" the current running instance. I'm checking using `wxSingleInstanceChecker` but I don't know how to "raise" the running one.

```
single = new wxSingleInstanceChecker;
if (single->IsAnotherRunning()) {
    wxDELETE(single); return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is how to send message to an existing process, but I don't know how to make the main frame of the process stay on top of all other windows. It seems to me that it is the job of the window manager, and can't or is difficult to be achieved by wxWidgets, you can make your window `wxSTAY_ON_TOP` though, when creating it. So, it is either "always on top" or minimized.

```
// BUILD: g++ this_file.cpp -Wall $(wx-config --cxxflags --libs net,core,base)
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/snglinst.h>
#include <wx/ipc.h>

class CConnection : public wxConnection
{
protected:
    bool OnExec(const wxString& topic, const wxString& data);
};
class CServer : public wxServer
{
public:
    wxConnectionBase *OnAcceptConnection(const wxString& topic) {
        return new CConnection;
    }
};

class CApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() {
        // Check if there is another process running.
        if (m_one.IsAnotherRunning()) {
            // Create a IPC client and use it to ask the existing process to show itself.
            wxClient *client = new wxClient;
            wxConnectionBase *conn = client->MakeConnection("localhost", "/tmp/a_socket" /* or a port number */, "a_topic");
            conn->Execute("raise");
            delete conn;
            delete client;
            // Don't enter the message loop.
            return false;
        }
        // Create the main frame.
        wxFrame *frm = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "There can be only one.");
        frm->Show(true);
        // Start a IPC server.
        m_server = new CServer;
        m_server->Create("/tmp/a_socket" /* or the same port number */);
        // Enter the message loop.
        return this->wxApp::OnInit();
    }
    int OnExit() {
        delete m_server;
        return this->wxApp::OnExit();
    }
private:
    wxSingleInstanceChecker m_one;
    CServer *m_server;
};
DECLARE_APP(CApp)
IMPLEMENT_APP(CApp)

bool CConnection::OnExec(const wxString& topic, const wxString& data)
{
    if (topic.compare("a_topic") == 0 && data.compare("raise") == 0) {
        wxTheApp->GetTopWindow()->Show(true); // This actually won't work.
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do need to use some kind of IPC as shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30011664/15275) and then you can just use `wxFrame::Raise()` to put it on top of the Z-order.

Notice that it's quite common to also forward the command line arguments of the second instance to the first one, e.g. to open the document specified on the command line in the existing instance, which explains why you really have to use IPC -- wxWidgets can't guess your command line syntax and, especially, semantics for you.